# Windows Phone style "Looping Selector" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In Windows Phone 7, it is possible to make a "Looping Selector", which can be used for various types of pickers.  It functions as list or selectbox that, when you scroll down, at the end of the list, it will wrap around to the first item in the list and vice versa.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API

This link might help a little.

My question: Is there a way that I could replicate this kind of functionality in HTML with Javascript?

Thanks.